# How to horizontally center a button in manipulate?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, output-formatting, button

I just need to center a button in the MWE code below.  Currently, all I try doesn't work.  I would like to horizontally center the button relative to the sliders over it, for aesthetical reasons only.

```
Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot[{y t^3 - u, x t^2 + z}, {t, -10, 10},
        PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2.5}, {0, 5}},
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        Frame -> True,
        Axes -> True,
        AxesOrigin -> {0, 1},
        GridLines -> Automatic,
        ImageSize -> 600
    ],
{{x, 1, "x"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large},
{{y, 1, "y"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large},
{{z, 1, "z"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large},
{{u, 0, "u"}, -2, 2, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large},
Delimiter,
Button["Button",{x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, u = 0},Appearance -> "Palette",ImageSize -> {256, 28}
],
ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

It's probably trivial, but can't find it !  :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the `Button` in a `Row`. Using the dimensions that you have given of `600` for the plot and `256` for the `Button` you would want the spacing to be the difference divided by two. You can adjust the spacing to your liking if it doesn't match your expectations.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{y t^3 - u, x t^2 + z}, {t, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2.5}, {0, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 600],

 {{x, 1, "x"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large},
 {{y, 1, "y"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large},
 {{z, 1, "z"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large},
 {{u, 0, "u"}, -2, 2, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large},
 Delimiter,
 Row[{
   Spacer[(600 - 256)/2],
   Button["Button", {x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, u = 0}, 
    Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> {256, 28}]
   }],
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update - Center all in Manipulate Window

In order to center the controls and the `Button` in the whole `Manipulate` window, place all of the controls in a centered column inside the `Row`. Set the `Alignment` of the column to center.

When placed inside a `Row`, `Grid` or `Column` one has to explicitly wrap the control with `Control` (see below).

Also one would have to build their own delimiter.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{y t^3 - u, x t^2 + z}, {t, -10, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2.5}, {0, 5}},
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1},
   GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 600],
 Row[{
   Spacer[(600 - 256)/2],
   Column[{
     Control[{{x, 1, "x"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> {265, 5}}], 
     Control[{{y, 1, "y"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> {256, 5}}], 
     Control[{{z, 1, "z"}, 0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> {256, 5}}], 
     Control[{{u, 0, "u"}, -2, 2, 0.01, ImageSize -> {256, 5}}], 
     Row[{Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
        ImageSize -> {256, 5}, AspectRatio -> 5/256]}],
     Button["Button", {x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, u = 0},
      Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> {256, 28}]
     }, Alignment -> Center]
   }],
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow !  Both solutions are nice.  Thanks guys.  I'm selecting this answer as the solution since it is simpler and fits very well my project.

Comment: Is there a way to place the button in the middle of the whole manipulate window ?

Comment: Depending upon how much work you want to put into it you have complete control over the 1Slider`, `Button`, `InputField`, etc.. I think of it as being three levels. First, using the default position from `Manipulate`. Second, place inside a `Row`, `Column` or `Grid` and wrap the control with `Control`. Third, put it where ever you like (even inside the plot) and use explicit control types with `Dynamic` inside the control. The latter is the most powerful but takes the most work. I have updated the answer to show you level two, how to center it in the plot.

Comment: Your last code doesn't work on my system.  It gives a frozen Manipulate window, and no warning/error messages !  I can't move the sliders.

Comment: @cham Sorry, I was too quick on the draw. The best I could do without going to level 3 (`Dynamic`) was to put the controls in a `Row` with a `Spacer` and a centered `Column`.

Comment: Ok, it's working great now.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to use `Grid` for complex layouts. One drawback is that `Delimiter` does not work as in the original `Manipulate`, the advantage is that you can use all styling options available to `Grid`, plus you don´t have to fiddle with discrete `ImageSize` values etc.:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{y t^3 - u, x t^2 + z}, {t, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2.5}, {0, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 600],
 Grid[{{Control@{{x, 1, "x"}, 0, 5, 0.01, 
      ImageSize -> Large}}, {Control@{{y, 1, "y"}, 0, 5, 0.01, 
      ImageSize -> Large}}, {Control@{{z, 1, "z"}, 0, 5, 0.01, 
      ImageSize -> Large}}, {Control@{{u, 0, "u"}, -2, 2, 0.01, 
      ImageSize -> Large}}, {Button[
     "Button", {x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, u = 0}, 
Appearance -> "Palette"]}}], ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the whole control block centered, this is easily added by applying an additional `Pane`:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{y t^3 - u, x t^2 + z}, {t, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2.5}, {0, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> {1000, 300}], 
 Pane[Grid[{{Control@{{x, 1, "x"}, 0, 5, 0.01, 
       ImageSize -> Large}}, {Control@{{y, 1, "y"}, 0, 5, 0.01, 
       ImageSize -> Large}}, {Control@{{z, 1, "z"}, 0, 5, 0.01, 
       ImageSize -> Large}}, {Control@{{u, 0, "u"}, -2, 2, 0.01, 
       ImageSize -> Large}}, {Button[
      "Button", {x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, u = 0}, Appearance -> "Palette",
       ImageSize -> Medium]}}], ImageSize -> 1000, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}], ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice !  However, I prefer the second solution, which is simpler.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad you like it! It sure is more work to begin with (although it tends to pay off for more complex layouts).

Comment: Is there a way to center the button relative to the Manipulate window width (which is not defined in the code) ?

Comment: @Cham comin up, standby... there you are.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer is pretty complete.