# Dynamically Center a Control in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I am attempting to dynamically horizontally center a button above the plot window in a manipulate.  For example,

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 4}],
 Row[{Spacer[20],Button["A"]}]]
```

I know I can use Spacer[] to move the button to right a set amount, however, I would like a solution that dynamically centers the button so that when I manually changed the size of the plot window, the button dynamically horizontally centers itself.

[image]

It seems like I would need access to the size of the plot window as it changes, but I'm not sure how to get at that information.  Any ideas?

Comment: Cham asked a follow-up question at the bottom of this post but no solution was offered. 
 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108891/how-to-horizontally-center-a-button-in-manipulate/108894#108894

Comment: From the underlying cell structure... it looks like I need to get at the ImageSizeCache for the plot window.  But not sure how to access it.

Comment: This `Row[{Spacer[ImageDimensions[g][[1]]/2], Button["A"]}]` where `g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 4}]` is not really a solution, since it´, indeed, places that button centered, but does not react dynamically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We make plot image size a control variable and use the (undocumented) `Method` option `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction"` to adjust the horizontal size of the display area. The display area content is wrapped in `Pane` with the option `Alignment -> {Center, Center}` to make display area content stay centered.

```
Manipulate[Plot[x Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> color, 
  ImageSize -> Dynamic[imagesize]],
 {{color, Red}, None},
 Button["A", color = color /. {Red->Green, Green->Red}, 
    ImageSize -> {Scaled[.1], Automatic}],
 {{imagesize, {300, 250}}, None}, 
 Method -> {"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" ->
    (Dynamic @ Pane[#, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
        ImageSize -> {First @ imagesize, Automatic}] &)}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[x Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> color, 
  ImageSize -> Dynamic[imagesize]], 
 Column[{Column[{Control@{a, -1, 1}, 
        Control@{b, {1, 2, 3} Pi/4},
        Control @ {{color, Red}, ColorSlider}}],
      Button["A", color = Darker @ color, ImageSize -> {30, Automatic}]}, 
  Alignment -> Center],
 {{imagesize, {300, 250}}, None}, 
 Method -> {"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> 
    (Dynamic @ Pane[#, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
        ImageSize -> {First @ imagesize, Automatic} &)}]
```

[image]

Comment: All this trouble because `ControlPlacement` does not allow position specifications like `{{Top, Center}}`, `{{Top, Right}}`, `{{Right, Center}}`, `{{Right, Bottom}}` etc.

Comment: Awesome!  It does seem like this should be built in.  Control placement is pretty important.

Comment: @kglr, How `imagesize` does know that it should take the value of the size of `Plot`?

Comment: @Rom38, great question!  Actually, I did not know that it would work. I had a hunch (based on having seen before that  `ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]`  tracks viewpoint as we interactively change a 3D graphics object) that it might; tried a simple example ( `is = 300; Graphics[{Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Dynamic[is],  PlotLabel -> Dynamic[is]]`) and saw that  it worked:)

Comment: @KGLR, MYstic mma :)